# Photorealism critique?

Tags: critique, blender

### Ignoring the background does this look photorealistic?

This is my first time modeling in Blender, but please be as harsh as you need to be.

Besides the photorealism any other critisim is highly encouraged.

I'm aware of https://blender.stackexchange.com/ but critiques are not welcome there.

Thank you!

I should mention this is a **polished** anvil. Apparently people polish the top.

[image]

Here's two of the reference photos below. I can't upload all the reference photos I used.

[image]

Comment: I think it looks good, maybe turn down the shininess slightly. I would post this question here instead https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?26-Focused-Critiques

Answer (score 3):

It's photorealistic, but who has scratched its work surfaces full of grooves? Normally anvils are used as hammering platforms. It can have gentle pits, shiny areas(Note1) and roundings at the edges, but deep scratches? How they are made by a blacksmith?

Note1: I have brought an old anvil. The blacksmith tried to sell it. He succeeded. The anvil was cleaned. The top surface of its nose and rounded edges were like polished chrome.

Comment: Photorealistic. The scratches don't bother me. The shininess comment makes me think its not silver underneath?

Comment: @user287001 Sorry I should have uploaded my reference images with it. Do you still think there's too many scratches there?

Comment: @LateralTerminal your scratches seem to be long and deep grooves, not random tear and wear

Comment: @user287001 thanks! I'll make a new map and upload the results. Should I do that as an edit or should I make a new question?

Comment: @LateralTerminal Write "added due the suggestions"  insert the new version, do not remove the old!

Answer (score 2):

The scratches look a bit wide to me, it gives me the sense that it's a very small anvil (more like something one would put on a keychain).

A quick google finds some images with much finer scratches, such as this one:

[image]

There also seems to be more hammered-looking bits in this image. I see you have some of that already which is looking good, but I think more variety would help.

I would suggest trying a couple different lighting setups and camera angles too. There is one comment about the roughness being a bit low (shiny), but I feel like the roughness might be a tad high, at least on the base. It's hard to judge from just one view; how reflections look depends greatly on the environment. Flat environments can look especially unrealistic sometimes, so you might try lighting it with a few different HDRs and see how it reacts.

Anyway, a very good-looking first project :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I actually did use HDR lighting + 2 lamps but I'll try messing with those settings. I put it on a grey plane because it looked like it was just floating in air with the HDR background XD.  If I had some table to put the anvil on that might help.